# save generated files with paperclip or carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

how can I save generated xls (without uploading form) file with paperclip or carriervawe to ActiveRecord and use it then to upload on amazon s3?

```
file = Tempfile.new(['conracts','.xlsx'])
      ToXls::Writer.new(content, {:columns => [:name, :address],
          :headers => ["name","address"]}).write_io(file)
          file.rewind
```

this is the xls file I generate , but i need to save it permanent in order to upload it with delayed job on s3.

Answer (score 0):

With Carrierwave, you can assign a normal file to the mountpoint of the uploader, then save the model.
Carrierwave will then handle all uploading.

So if you have a model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :xml_file, XmlUploader
end
```

you can write

```
pro=Project.new
pro.xml_file = file # your generated tempfile
pro.save
```

I'm not familiar with paperclip.

Comment: yes but if my model is Users and i generate a xls file wit all the records from the model, and then save it like you show me above, then i save all the model again? i mean i have export button for exporting , but how can i save only the file in the model and then upload it? and not save all the records over again?

Comment: If you can generate the XML before saving your model, just do so, assign the file and save the model afterwards.